# How to sync data from AWS S3 bucket to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: file-synchronization, cloud-service, cloud-storage, cloud, azure

I need to have a sync between AWS S3 bucket to Azure Blob Storage.

AWS propose something really smart called [DataSync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/creating-azure-blob-location.html) but that only works **AWS <-- Azure** and not the other way around (smart *******!).

The only sync **AWS --> Azure** seems [S3-to-Blob](https://github.com/StratusOn/S3-to-Blob). Which looks unmaintained and provided by god-only-knows-whom.

On the Azure Marketplace I haven't find anything.

I cannot be the only one having this problem right?

Any alternative?